# Getting Juniper Network Connect VPN working on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, vpn

When trying to get Juniper Network Connect working on my Mac with OSX 10.6, the Java app seems to get stuck indefinitely on the "Getting Authentication" step which prevents the network connect software from installing

I am able to install and connect to the remote network on Windows 7 and Linux machines at the same location.

Is this an issue with OSX?

Answer (score 3):

After the attempted/failed installation, open the "Terminal" application and paste this:

sudo tar -C / -xvf /tmp/NetworkConnectBinaries.pax

Press "Enter". You will prompted to enter your password. Now you can re-launch Network Connect from Safari/Firefox, and the installation should go through this time.

Technical mumbo jumbo: it looks like the java app is unable to untar the installation binaries from the /tmp folder.

This solution was posted by Raj in the comments of this blog post: http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/connections-to-juniper-network-connect-vpn-failing-in-safari-6-1-and-safari-7/#comment-4967